# Rollup config for React component library not working with SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, rollupjs

I'm trying to set up a React component library using Rollup, which my React app then installs and uses. The consuming React application is being rendered on the server. I have managed to get this set up working with Webpack, wherein I'm bundling my React component library into one single file and sending it down. Problem is this is a huge file and negates the point of SSR (part of it at least) as it takes a long time to download.

So I decided to use Rollup to split up the components into individual ES modules which are then pulled in and used as required by the app. The problem is that I can't get this to work with SSR at all. This is my first time using Rollup so I may have missed something obvious. Here is my `rollup.config.js`

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import namedDeps from './named-dependencies';
import stylus from './rollup-plugin-stylus-v2';
import postcssUrl from './rollup-plugin-postcss-url';
import autoExternal from 'rollup-plugin-auto-external';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import fs from 'fs';

const namedDepsObject = namedDeps
  .map(depPath => ({
    keys: Object.keys(require(depPath)).filter(v => v !== 'default'),
    name: depPath,
  }))
  .reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val.name] = val.keys;
    return acc;
  }, {});

let ComponentsList = require('./components-file'); // This has an array of component src and name

const rollConfigObject = fileName => {
  const configOpts = {
    input: `${fileName.src}`,
    output: [
      {
         file: `dist/ssr/esm/${fileName.name}.js`,
         format: 'esm',
      }
    ],
    plugins: [
      autoExternal(),
      url({
        include: ['**/*.svg', '**/*.png', '**/*.jpg', '**/*.gif', '**/*.woff', '**/*.woff2', '**/*.eot', '**/*.ttf', ],
        emitFiles: false
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
        runtimeHelpers: true,
      }),
      resolve(),
      commonjs({
        sourceMap: false,
        namedExports: {
          ...namedDepsObject,
        },
      }),
      image(),
      json(),
      stylus(),
      postcssUrl(),
      css({
        output: function(styles, styleNodes){
          fs.appendFileSync(__dirname + '/dist/ssr/styles.css', styles);
        }
      }),
    ],
  };
  return { ...configOpts };
};

export default ComponentsList.map(
  moduleName => {
    return rollConfigObject(moduleName);
  }
)
```

Now this creates the separate component bundles like I want, but the problem is that it seems to be including code within the `createCommonjsModule` methods from `node_modules` which is then injecting browser objects like `document`, which when I attempt to render on the server throws an error.

I am trying to not include node_modules at all, so when I try to run this with only the `babel` plugin, it throws an `Error: Could not resolve entry module` and refuses to build. An example is Braintree, it's adding a lot of code with `document` usage.
I'm not sure how to get it to not inject node_modules code within the component. In the app, I'm using Webpack to run these modules through babel, but objects like `document` will pass through and then refuse to work on the server.

Any suggestions would be great here, been struggling with this for a number of days now. Thanks!

Comment: Any luck? Seems like the people from `rollup` are too busy to worry about the peasant

Comment: Get any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I got the config to work after I updated my babel setting to

```
 babel({
        exclude: [
          '../../node_modules/**',
          '../node_modules/**',
          'node_modules/**',
        ],
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/env',
            {
              modules: false,
              targets: {
                esmodules: true,
              },
            },
          ],
          '@babel/react',
        ],
        plugins: [
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
          '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
          '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        ],
        runtimeHelpers: true,
      }),
 commonjs({ sourceMap: false }),
```